# Automapper mapping issue: flattening from DTO to ViewModel works - doesn't work the other way around

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

My DTOs (simplified for demonstration purposes):

Item (the DTO mapped to my ViewModel in question):

```
public class Item {
    public Item() { }
    public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
}
```

ItemType (referenced by my Item class):

```
public class ItemType {
    public ItemType() { }
    public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My ViewModel (for editing my Item class data):

```
public class ItemEditViewModel {
    public ItemEditViewModel () { }
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid ItemTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public SelectList ItemTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ItemType> ItemTypeEntities { get; set; }

    public BuildItemTypesSelectList(Guid? itemTypeID)
    {
        ItemTypes = new SelectList(ItemTypeEntities, "ID", "Name", itemTypeID);
    }
}
```

My AutoMapper mapping code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Item, ItemEditViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemTypes, opt => opt.Ignore());
Mapper.CreateMap<ItemEditViewModel, Item>();
```

Controller code (again, simplified for demonstration):

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var itemVM = new ItemEditViewModel();
    // Populates the ItemTypeEntities and ItemTypes properties in the ViewModel:
    PopulateEditViewModelWithItemTypes(itemVM, null);
    return View(itemVM);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ItemEditViewModel itemVM)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        Item newItem = new Item();
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(itemVM, newItem);
        newItem.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        ...
        // Validation and saving code here...
        ...
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    PopulateEditViewModelWithItemTypes(itemVM, null);
    return View(itemVM);
}
```

**Now, here's what's happening:**

Within my HttpPost Create action result in my controller where I use Automapper to map my ItemEditViewModel to my Item DTO class, the ItemType ID value selected in the SelectList doesn't bind to the Item.ItemType.ID property. The Item.ItemType property is null.

I assume this is because, since I don't have an ItemTypeID Guid value in my Item DTO class, and I haven't created a new ItemType class for the property of the same name in my Item DTO, AutoMapper is unable to store the ItemType ID value.

I think it comes down to my Automapper mapping configuration.

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm overlooking.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure this is because automapper was designed as a Big Shape-> Smaller/Flat Shape mapping tool, not the other way around.  This just isn't supported.

Comment: That's disappointing. It seems as though, within my mapping configuration for my ViewModel to DTO, that I'd be able to specify a constructor for the ItemType class to which to bind my selected ItemTypeID from the ViewModel. I already have a constructor for ItemType that accepts a Guid parameter for the ID. Right now, I've modified my Create HttpPost ActionResult method to set the DTO's ItemType property to a new ItemType object by using the constructor: newItem.ItemType = new ItemType(itemVM.ItemTypeID);

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to say:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ItemEditViewModel, Item>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
        {
            return new ItemType()
                {
                    ID = src.ItemTypeID
                }
        };
```